# Update headers in a nodejs http.request

Tags: node.js, oauth

There is a way in nodejs to modify response headers  when calling a second nested http.request that return some data from another server ?
I always get this error, from the below functions...

```
 catch error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Main function from where I call to check if the token is valid:
     req.on('end', function (){
            console.log('GET to /api, Do I have privileges with %s?', access_token);
            validadToken(req, res, next);
        });

This is the funciton to validate the token against the OAuth2 server, if the respond is 401, I tried to obtain an new refresh_token:

```
    function validadToken (req, res, next ) {
        var options = { port: 8080, 
                        path: '/api', 
                        host: 'localhost', 
                        method: 'GET' , 
                        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ access_token,
                              'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} };
        req2 = http.request(options, 
            function (response){
                response.setEncoding('utf8');
                response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    console.log(".-response=> ", chunk);
                    console.log("statusCode: " + response.statusCode);

                    if(response.statusCode == 401){
                        console.log();
                        console.log("===>>>> call to renew / wait for me");
                        renewToken(response, res, next); 

                    }else if(response.statusCode === 200){
                        console.log("Valid Token... we keep it going!");
                    }
                    next();             
                });  
            });
        req2.write(formData);

        req2.end();         
}
```

From here I try to get the refresh token, but when I try to update the new value in the headers  I get the above error. The value for refresh_token is recovery from a response from the previously function

```
    function renewToken (req, res){
    var userUrl = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token='+refresh_token+'&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX';
    var optRenew = {    port: 8080, 
                        path: '/token', 
                        host: 'localhost', 
                        method: 'POST' , 
                        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} };

    renew = http.request(optRenew, 
            function (responseRenew){
              console.log("responseRenew");
              responseRenew.setEncoding('utf8');

              responseRenew.on('data', function (chunk){
                        console.log(".-responseRenew=> ", chunk);
                        console.log(".-responseRenew=> ", responseRenew.statusCode);
                        accessTokenValue = getToken("access_token", chunk, ',', ':', '"');
                        refreshTokenValue = getToken("refresh_token", chunk, ',', ':', '"'); 
                        console.log("Headers Sent (renew) ? "+ res.headersSent);
                        console.log("¡¡¡New values!!!\n" + accessTokenValue +' '+ refreshTokenValue);     

                        res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", ["ninja="+accessTokenValue, "samurai="+refreshTokenValue]);
                        console.log("envio ....");
                      })
            });
    renew.write(userUrl);
    renew.end();  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it

```
if(response.statusCode == 401) {
  console.log();
  console.log("===>>>> call to renew / wait for me");
  renewToken(response, res, next); 

} else if(response.statusCode === 200) {
  console.log("Valid Token... we keep it going!");
}
next();
```

When the token doesn't need to be renewed you call `next` and all is ok, but when `renewToken` is called you have a problem: `http.request` is an asynchronous call, `renewToken` returns before the code that process the renew response is executed, so the call to `next` is done before the renewed token is known. When you call `next` the next middleware is called, here probably the next middleware will send back the response before the renewed token will be available and this explains your error: after the next middleware completes the response you try to set one of the response headers

The solution actually is really easy (I'll skip some code)

```
function validadToken(req, res, next) {
  ...
  req2 = http.request(options, function (response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      ...
      if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        ...
        renewToken(req, res, next); 

      } else if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log("Valid Token... we keep it going!");
        next();
      } else {
        // TODO: you should deal with the other cases
      }                
    });  
  });
  req2.write(formData);
  req2.end();         
}

function renewToken(req, res, next) {
  ...

  renew = http.request(optRenew, function (responseRenew){
     ...
     responseRenew.on('data', function(chunk){
       ...    
       res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", ["ninja="+accessTokenValue, "samurai="+refreshTokenValue]);
       console.log("envio ....");

       // NOW IT'S THE TIME TO CALL THE NEXT MIDDLEWARE
       next()
     })
   });
   renew.write(userUrl);
   renew.end();  
}
```

TL;DR; you should call `next` only after you got the token

Comment: It works, the next() calling always was sending the response.